# need to find odd number of ones in the substring of binary representation of non negative integer

Tags: java, string, optimization

I tried using some other logic instead of substring but still Code is taking more time then expected. I want to optimize below code. Please help me with suggestions

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Binary {

public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.println(count(sc.nextBigInteger()));
    }

}

static int count(BigInteger x) {
    int count = 0;
    String xx = x.toString(2);

    int n = xx.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            String test = xx.substring(i, j).intern();
            if (!test.matches("^0*(?:10*10*)*$"))
                count++;

        }
    }
    return count;
 }
     }
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/q/30455472/7939871

Comment: Do not expect bruteforcing to be fast. You could easily eliminate the regex by observing how the count of ones changes when `j` gets incremented. You could do the same for `i`. This would gain a huge factor, but you could probably do much better: Given a string `s` with `count(s) = N`, what are `count(s + '0')` and `count(s + 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you need to follow is Dynamic Programming with memoization. These will solve the time out issue. First try to solve it using recursion, then follow DP approach. Just follow below link to know the approach.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overlapping-subproblems-property-in-dynamic-programming-dp-1/